# Google App Engine uploading multi-module project - Bad configuration: XML error validating

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I built a 2-module application for Google App Engine that runs fine in the development server.  But when I tried to upload it I got this error:

```
Bad configuration: XML error validating /Users/mosofsky/Developer/AudienceMarketing/audiencemarketing-ear/target/audiencemarketing-ear-1.0/audiencemarketing-frontend-1.0.war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml against /Users/mosofsky/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.15/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.15/docs/appengine-web.xsd
  Caused by: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'module'. One of '{"http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":source-language, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":instance-class, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":automatic-scaling, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":manual-scaling, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":basic-scaling, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":static-files, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":resource-files, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":system-properties, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":vm-settings, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":vm-health-check, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":env-variables, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":ssl-enabled, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":sessions-enabled, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":async-session-persistence, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":user-permissions, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":public-root, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":inbound-services, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":precompilation-enabled, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":admin-console, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":static-error-handlers, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":warmup-requests-enabled, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":threadsafe, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":auto-id-policy, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":code-lock, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":vm, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":pagespeed, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":class-loader-config, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":url-stream-handler, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":use-google-connector-j}' is expected.
Please see the logs [/var/folders/dp/v_lw6kqx16bf7743hs5t9phc0000gn/T/appcfg5761671119313466239.log] for further information.
MOsofsky-MacBookPro:audiencemarketing-ear mosofsky$
```

Here are my two appengine-web.xml files:

appengine-web.xml for audiencemarketing-frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>audience-marketing</application> 
    <version>${appengine.app.version}</version>
    <module>audiencemarketing-frontend</module>   
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

appengine-web.xml for audiencemarketing-backend:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>audience-marketing</application>
    <version>${appengine.app.version}</version>
    <module>audiencemarketing-backend</module>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>

    <instance-class>B8</instance-class>
    <basic-scaling>
        <max-instances>11</max-instances>
    </basic-scaling>

</appengine-web-app>
```

And here is my application.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
  <display-name>appengine-modules-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>audiencemarketing-frontend-1.0.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/audiencemarketing-frontend</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>audiencemarketing-backend-1.0.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/audiencemarketing-backend</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

I assume by listing audiencemarketing-frontend first in the application.xml file it should be treated as the default module.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing:

> Default module
>
> The default module is defined by explicitly giving a module the name
>   "default," or by not including the name parameter in the module's
>   config file. Requests that specify no module or an invalid module are
>   routed to the default module. You can use the Admin Console to
>   designate a default version for a module, when appropriate.

Therefore the module I want to be default should not have a  element.  The correction is this for the

appengine-web.xml for audiencemarketing-frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>audience-marketing</application> 
    <version>${appengine.app.version}</version>
<!--    <module>audiencemarketing-frontend</module>   OFFENDING LINE REMOVED -->
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

This fixed the problem, I was then able to upload and run my app.